# How to merge 2 dataframe in Spark (Scala)?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am new in Spark Framework and need some help!

Assume that the first DataFrame (`df1`) stores the time that users access the call center.

```
+---------+-------------------+
|USER_NAME|       REQUEST_DATE|
+---------+-------------------+
|     Mark|2018-02-20 00:00:00|
|     Alex|2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|      Bob|2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|     Mark|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
|     Kate|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
+---------+-------------------+
```

The second DataFrame stores information about whether a person is a member of the organization. OUT means that the user has left the organization. `IN` means that the user has come to the organization. `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` mean the beginning and end of the corresponding process.

For example, you can see that `Alex` left the organization at `2018-01-01 00:00:00`, and this process ended at `2018-02-01 00:00:00`. You can notice that one user can come and left the organization at different times as `Mark`.

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|NAME     | START_DATE          | END_DATE            | STATUS |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|     Alex| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
|      Bob| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-05 00:00:00 | IN     |
|     Mark| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | IN     |
|     Mark| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | 2018-08-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
|    Meggy| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | OUT    |
+----------+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to get such a DataFrame in the final. It must contain all records from the first DataFrame plus a column indicating whether the Person is a member of the organization at the time of the request (`REQUEST_DATE`) or not.

```
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
|USER_NAME|       REQUEST_DATE| USER_STATUS    |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
|     Mark|2018-02-20 00:00:00| Our user       |
|     Alex|2018-03-01 00:00:00| Not our user   |
|      Bob|2018-03-01 00:00:00| Our user       |
|     Mark|2018-07-01 00:00:00| Our user       |
|     Kate|2018-07-01 00:00:00| No Information |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
```

I tried next code, but in `finalDF` I have error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Also in final result I need datetime. Right now in `lastRowByRequestId` I have only date without time.

**CODE**:

```
val df1 = Seq(
    ("Mark", "2018-02-20 00:00:00"),
    ("Alex", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Bob", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Mark", "2018-07-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Kate", "2018-07-01 00:00:00")
).toDF("USER_NAME", "REQUEST_DATE")

df1.show()

val df2 = Seq(
    ("Alex", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "OUT"),
    ("Bob", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-05 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Mark", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-03-01 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Mark", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2018-08-01 00:00:00", "OUT"),
    ("Meggy", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "OUT")
).toDF("NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "STATUS")

df2.show()

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class UserAndRequest(
                           USER_NAME:String,
                           REQUEST_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           START_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           END_DATE:java.sql.Date,
                           STATUS:String,
                           REQUEST_ID:Long
                         )

val joined : Dataset[UserAndRequest] = df1.withColumn("REQUEST_ID", monotonically_increasing_id).
  join(df2,$"USER_NAME" === $"NAME", "left").
  as[UserAndRequest]

val lastRowByRequestId = joined.
  groupByKey(_.REQUEST_ID).
  reduceGroups( (x,y) =>
    if (x.REQUEST_DATE.getTime > x.END_DATE.getTime && x.END_DATE.getTime > y.END_DATE.getTime) x else y
  ).map(_._2)

def logic(status: String): String = {
  if (status == "IN") "Our user"
  else if (status == "OUT") "not our user"
  else "No Information"
}

val logicUDF = udf(logic _)

val finalDF = lastRowByRequestId.withColumn("USER_STATUS",logicUDF($"REQUEST_DATE"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code and run it. It works with minor update. I replaced REQUEST_DATE By STATUS. Also, Note: Spark not serialized task most cases happened when you don't use case class but from Spark 2.x case classes is encoded automatically in Spark tasks.

```
val finalDF = lastRowByRequestId.withColumn("USER_STATUS",logicUDF($"STATUS"))
```

Below is the output

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------+----------+--------------+
|USER_NAME|REQUEST_DATE|START_DATE|  END_DATE|STATUS|REQUEST_ID|   USER_STATUS|
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------+----------+--------------+
|     Mark|  2018-02-20|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|    IN|         0|      Our user|
|     Alex|  2018-03-01|2018-01-01|2018-02-01|   OUT|         1|  not our user|
|     Mark|  2018-07-01|2018-02-01|2018-03-01|    IN|         3|      Our user|
|      Bob|  2018-03-01|2018-02-01|2018-02-05|    IN|         2|      Our user|
|     Kate|  2018-07-01|      null|      null|  null|         4|No Information|
+---------+------------+----------+----------+------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hello! In fact I use `case class`. For thats why I am little bit confused. This code raise such error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. Maybe I need replace `case class` and initialize in other place? Also how in final result have date and time. As you can see right now I have only date without time. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, I change code inside case class from `DATE_TIME: java.sql.Date` to `DATE_TIME: java.sql.Timestamp`. After that I see date and time. Now problem only: `Task not serializable`. How I can fix it?

Comment: Remove it in another class and call it